# featureId filtering in wfs openlayers

Tags: filtering, openlayers, geoserver

I want to define a featureId fiter for wfs layer like below:

```
wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS Vectore", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.1.0",
            srsName: "EPSG:4326",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iran/wms?service=WFS",
            featureType: "population",
            featureNS: "http://iran.kadaster.org",
            geometryName: "the_geom"
        }),
        filter:
            new OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureId({
                fids: ['population.913', 'population.912']
                //type: ?????
            })

    });
```

I don't know to what set 'type' variable in filtering option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was set fids field. When you set fids to `['population.913', 'population.912']`, this means a feature that it's fids equal to `'population.913'` and `'population.912'`. If you set fids field to `'population.912'` or `'population.913'` you get correct response

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'type' property on filter type FeatureId.

[API doc](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Filter/FeatureId-js.html)

This is enough.

```
filter:new OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureId({
                fids: ['population.913', 'population.912'];

            });
```

Comment: you're right. The problem was set fids field. When you set fids to ['population.913', 'population.912'], this means a feature that it's fids equal to 'population.913' and 'population9.12'. If you set fids field to 'population.912' or 'population.913' you get correct response.